# Алгоритм последовательности выигрыша

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, алгоритм, математика

У меня есть последовательность из выигрышей и проигрышей. Моя цель - выяснить, как часто выигрывает раздача, сразу после выигрышной раздачи. То есть, если одна раздача выиграла, то узнать, как часто выигрывает следующая за ней раздача.
Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как быть в ситуации, когда выигрывает первая раздача, за ней вторая - это значит успех. А если выигрывает за второй раздачей третья, то как быть? Считать, что она идёт в зачёт, или обнулять и считать, что выигрывает третья и четвёртая раздачи. А не вторая и третья. Как считать правильно? 1, 2 и 3, 4 или 1, 2, 3, 4, так как четыре подряд выигрышных раздачи.
 Помогите пожалуйста, кто хочет.

Я построил такой алгоритм:
a - счётчик первой выигрышной раздачи
b - счётчик выигрышной раздачи, если она идёт сразу после a.
c - считает, сколько раздач подряд было выиграно.
hand - раздача

```
if hand == true:
    a = a + 1
    c = c + 1
        if c == 2:
            b = b + 1
            с = 0
else: c = 0
```

Comment: Какова вероятность выиграть в одной раздаче (партии)? Если постоянная, то у вас распределение Бернулли.

Comment: Я считаю, что это неважно, так как вопрос в другом - как считать правильно 1 и 2, и сбрасывать счётчик, или 1, 2, 3, 4... пока не наступит проигрышная раздача.

Comment: Тогда количество пар true true. Так как раздачи независимы, то вероятность выигрыша после выигрыша не меняется. Например TTFTTTF. Искомое событие TT наступало 3 раза. Всего исходов 6. Вероятность 3/6=0.5

Comment: becouse, я Вас понял, но шанс выиграть не 100% всё равно. Просто, если я из четырёх раздач, которые шли подряд, буду считать 1,2 и 3,4, то это одна последовательность, а значит и результат другой, в отличии от 1,2,3,4, где 1,2 и 2,3, и 3,4 - тут уже три. Надеюсь Вы меня понимаете.

Comment: Вы четко обозначили событие А=TT. В опыте TTTT оно наступает 3 раза.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Настоятельно не рекомендую в подобных ситуациях копать в математическое решение задачи: в большинстве случаев вас ждет простейшее алгоритмическое решение.

```
items = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
count = 0
for index in range(0, len(items) - 1, 1):
    if items[index] == 1 and items[index + 1] == 1:
        count = count + 1

print(count)
```

Просто пробегитесь по массиву, проверяя текущий элемент и идущий далее. Доходите до предпоследнего элемента массива.

Comment: Спасибо. Я уж запутался.

Answer (score 1):

Ппростое однострочное решение:

```
items = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
count = sum(1 for t in zip(items[:-1], items[1:]) if t == (1, 1))
print(count)
```

[Демо](https://rextester.com/RXGP65755).